# Bluetooth won't detect and reconnect to devices

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I currently have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS installed on a Dell XPS 15 9550 and when I first tried connecting my bluetooth audio devices (logitech x300 and sony mdr-1000x) they paired successfully and worked great. However, a little bit later I tried connecting to the devices again it wouldn't work. I forgot the devices on ubuntu and tried repairing but the bluetooth settings couldn't detect either of my devices. I tried reinstalling bluetooth drivers but that didn't change anything. What should I do to fix these problems? Any help would be appreciated.